# How to set Google dialer as the default dialer in Sony Xperia Z3+?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calls, default-applications, sony-xperia-z3

I hope you are well. I have recently switched from a Google Nexus 5 to a Sony Xperia Z3+. However, I'm slightly annoyed at all of the default apps that Sony bundle with it. I have already replaced the Xperia keyboard with the one from Google, and that was fairly easy. I am now trying to replace the default dialer with the awesome Google dialer that I am used to.

I managed to find online an APK for the Google dialer (all verified as genuine) and installed it to my phone. However, I cannot find the option to select it as the default dialer.

I went to Settings → Apps → All → Google Dialer.

The 'Launch by default' option is greyed out. Does anyone know how to get this working as I really love being able to search for a number by typing the name of a company and don't like the Sony dialer?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to clear out the default for the Sony Dialer first.

```
Settings > Apps > All > [insert Sony dialer app here] > Clear Defaults
```

I find that dialing a number from your contacts may not prompt you for a new default, either. Instead, navigate to a website that has a properly formatted number like`(###) ###-####` that you can tap on to have it open in a dialer - that should prompt you for a default selection.

After your default is selected, you can disable the old dialer so it doesn't show up in your app list.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried all of this already. It appears that the Sony dialer cannot be disabled in any way nor can the Google dialer be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Frustrating - Sony phone app is clunky - and I hate the way it jumps into the "I'll call you back" nonsense - and then does not allow you to cancel that and pickup the call.

I installed Lollipop phone dialer - but as you note - no way to set it as the default.

However - in Settings / Apps / All - you can disable their Text app, and then Force Stop their Phone app. However - it still rings and opens. Go figure.  Looks like this will require an Android developer access hack to break open :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by going to Settings > Apps > then click the gear icon in upper right corner for the "Configure Apps" options.  Under "Advanced" choose "Default Apps" and change "Phone App" to the Google Dialer.  It was "Contacts" originally.  You might get prompted at the next time you tap a # to dial out, but just choose the Google Dialer and select "Always" at the prompts to make it the global default.

-- Note I'm on a Z5 using Android 6.0.1 so my menu structure might be a bit different.

Answer (score -2):

First, make sure you have the latest version of the app that is compatible with your device.
You can get it via [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer) or via [APKMirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-phone/).
You need [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) to install APKs.

Usually, when you want to set an app as default, you need to clear the previous defaults.

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhzeR.png) /
[Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b1qD.png) /
[Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzjER.png) /
[Open by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBKrI.png) /
[Clear defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBKrI.png)

You can also
[`DISABLE`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo8h1.png) +
[`FORCE STOP`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo8h1.png) +
[`CLEAR DATA`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH2kl.png)
the unwanted app to make it easier to change the default behaviour.

Then, normally, in
[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhzeR.png) /
[Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b1qD.png) /
[Configure apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jRnG.png) /
[Phone app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo8h1.png),
you should be able to select your desired phone app.

If this doesn't work, then you need a custom Android.

---

Do you have [z3](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=z3), [z3c](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=z3c), [z3dual](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=z3dual), [scorpion](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=scorpion) or [scorpion_windy](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=scorpion_windy)?

Either way, you should get [CyanogenMod](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/) and [OpenGApps](http://opengapps.org/), then install them using [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads). This will allow you to do way more than just changing the default phone app.

---

I know this isn't the place for personal opinions, but here's mine : Refund that and get back your Nexus 5.